# C# datareader & T-SQL TOP 10

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datareader

I'm just trying to list the top 10 results from a number of tables that are unioned via union all. Allough I can't get it to list the top 10 in the datareader, can anyone help?

Below code is just to union the 10 tables together via 3 search parameters and return top 1 from the 'Q1' column.

```
        SqlCeConnection myConnectionQ1 = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = Events.sdf");
        myConnectionQ1.Open();
        SqlCeCommand myCommandQ1 = myConnectionQ1.CreateCommand();
        myCommandQ1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM(SELECT Q1, EventName, SR1SessionRaceName, LapNumber, SR1BikeSetup, Date, Track, Number, Rider FROM SR1Laptimes WHERE Q1 IS NOT NULL) as Tbl1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM(SELECT Q1, EventName, SR2SessionRaceName, LapNumber, SR2BikeSetup, Date, Track, Number, Rider FROM SR2Laptimes WHERE Q1 IS NOT NULL) as Tbl2 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM(SELECT Q1, EventName, SR3SessionRaceName, LapNumber, SR3BikeSetup, Date, Track, Number, Rider FROM SR3Laptimes WHERE Q1 IS NOT NULL) as Tbl3 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM(SELECT Q1, EventName, SR4SessionRaceName, LapNumber, SR4BikeSetup, Date, Track, Number, Rider FROM SR4Laptimes WHERE Q1 IS NOT NULL) as Tbl4 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM(SELECT Q1, EventName, SR5SessionRaceName, LapNumber, SR5BikeSetup, Date, Track, Number, Rider FROM SR5Laptimes WHERE Q1 IS NOT NULL) as Tbl5 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM(SELECT Q1, EventName, SR6SessionRaceName, LapNumber, SR6BikeSetup, Date, Track, Number, Rider FROM SR6Laptimes WHERE Q1 IS NOT NULL) as Tbl6 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM(SELECT Q1, EventName, SR7SessionRaceName, LapNumber, SR7BikeSetup, Date, Track, Number, Rider FROM SR7Laptimes WHERE Q1 IS NOT NULL) as Tbl7 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM(SELECT Q1, EventName, SR8SessionRaceName, LapNumber, SR8BikeSetup, Date, Track, Number, Rider FROM SR8Laptimes WHERE Q1 IS NOT NULL) as Tbl8 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM(SELECT Q1, EventName, SR9SessionRaceName, LapNumber, SR9BikeSetup, Date, Track, Number, Rider FROM SR9Laptimes WHERE Q1 IS NOT NULL) as Tbl9 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM(SELECT Q1, EventName, SR10SessionRaceName, LapNumber, SR10BikeSetup, Date, Track, Number, Rider FROM SR10Laptimes WHERE Q1 IS NOT NULL) as Tbl10) as TblALL WHERE (Track = @track) AND (Number = @number) AND (Rider = @rider) ORDER BY Q1 ASC";
        myCommandQ1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@track", analysisTrackComboBox.Text);
        myCommandQ1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", analysisNumberComboBox.Text);
        myCommandQ1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rider", analysisRiderComboBox.Text);
        SqlCeDataReader myDataReaderQ1;
        myDataReaderQ1 = myCommandQ1.ExecuteReader();
        myDataReaderQ1.Read();
        daQ1tTextBox.Text = myDataReaderQ1[0].ToString();
        daenq1TextBox.Text = myDataReaderQ1[1].ToString();
        dasrnq1TextBox.Text = myDataReaderQ1[2].ToString();
        dalnq1TextBox.Text = myDataReaderQ1[3].ToString();
        dabsq1TextBox.Text = myDataReaderQ1[4].ToString();
        DateTime DTout1 = Convert.ToDateTime(myDataReaderQ1[5]);
        dadq1TextBox.Text = DTout1.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        myDataReaderQ1.Close();
        myConnectionQ1.Close();
```

Comment: Where do you tell it to take the top 10 in your query?

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Is it your data reader not displaying or your not getting correct results back? Because your data reader looks wrong because in this it looks like your only taking one result.  Usually it is something like while (reader.read ()) do something

Comment: I haven't told it Top 10 yet. I was just going to put it at the front "Select top (10 )...

Comment: When I did a while reader.read it stopped giving me asc

Comment: Reduce your complexity - figure out how it works - readd complexity. Do this by a) simplify your query to just one select b) add your reader in a loop to read the data from the reader b) remember if you use `.Text = ` you'll overwrite the text, not add to the text per iteration. Once that works start doing your actual query.

Comment: I've got it working by doing what you suggested. Now I just need to handle empty list rows.

Comment: List<string> q1top10 = new List<string>();
            while (myDataReaderT10Q1.Read())
            {
                q1top10.Add(myDataReaderT10Q1[0].ToString());
            }
            q11TextBox.Text = q1top10[0];
            q12TextBox.Text = q1top10[1];
            q13TextBox.Text = q1top10[2];...
          
            q110TextBox.Text = q1top10[9];
            myDataReaderT10Q1.Close();
            myConnectionT10Q1.Close();

Comment: Your union is pulling back everything when you only want a particular track, number and rider. Move that into each part of the union and cut down on the number of records you are working with.  Learn how to incorporate 'Using' statements in your C# code to handle disposing and closing connections easier.